# How can I improve this nested for loop?

Tags: python

I want to re-write the function get_bs in a different way, how can I improve this nested for loop, may be in a more compact way? Any suggestions?

I was thinking, may be split the nested loop in two different nested loops and each writing in one line, e.g. for i,j in....
Is this possible? Can someone please show me? Thanks.

```
class NB:
def __init__(self, train_data, test_data):
    self.train_data = train_data
    self.test_data = test_data
    self.train_entries = []
    self.test_entries = []
    self.diabetes_yes = []
    self.diabetes_no = []
    self.a_diabetesyes = []
    self.a_diabetesno = []
    self.b_diabetesyes = []
    self.b_diabetesno = []
    self.num_elements = 0
    self.p_diabetesyes = 0
    self.p_diabetesno = 0
    self.num_diabetesyes = 0
    self.num_diabetesno = 0

def trainNB(self):
    self.traincleandata()
    for i in range(self.num_elements - 1):
        self.a_diabetesyes[i] = sum(self.diabetes_yes[i]) / len(self.diabetes_yes[i])
        self.a_diabetesno[i] = sum(self.diabetes_no[i]) / len(self.diabetes_no[i])
    self.get_bs()

def traincleandata(self):
    for line in self.train_data:
        if self.num_elements == 0:
            self.num_elements = len(line.split(','))
            for i in range(self.num_elements):
                self.diabetes_yes.append([])
                self.diabetes_no.append([])
                self.a_diabetesyes.append(0.0)
                self.a_diabetesno.append(0.0)
                self.b_diabetesyes.append(0.0)
                self.b_diabetesno.append(0.0)
        params = line.split(',')
        cleanparams = getcleanparams(params)
        entry = Entry(cleanparams)
        self.train_entries.append(entry)

        for i in range(len(entry.elements) - 1):
            if (entry.diabetes == "yes"):
                self.diabetes_yes[i].append(Decimal(entry.elements[i]))
            else:
                self.diabetes_no[i].append(Decimal(entry.elements[i]))

        if (entry.diabetes == 'yes'):
            self.p_diabetesyes += 1
            self.num_diabetesyes += 1
        else:
            self.p_diabetesno += 1
            self.num_diabetesno += 1

    self.p_diabetesyes = Decimal(self.p_diabetesyes) / Decimal(len(self.train_entries))
    self.p_diabetesno = Decimal(self.p_diabetesno) / Decimal(len(self.train_entries))

def get_bs(self):

    sigSumYes = [0] * self.num_elements
    sigSumNo = [0] * self.num_elements

    for i in range(self.num_elements - 1):
        for j in range(self.num_diabetesyes):
            diff_yes = self.diabetes_yes[i][j] - self.a_diabetesyes[i]
            sigSumYes[i] += m.pow(diff_yes, 2)
        self.b_diabetesyes[i] = m.sqrt(sigSumYes[i] / (len(self.diabetes_yes[i]) - 1))
        for j in range(self.num_diabetesno):
            diff_no = self.diabetes_no[i][j] - self.a_diabetesno[i]
            sigSumNo[i] += m.pow(diff_no, 2)
        self.b_diabetesno[i] = m.sqrt(sigSumNo[i] / (len(self.diabetes_no[i]) - 1))

def testNB(self):
    self.testcleandata()
    self.testalgo()

def testcleandata(self):
    for line in self.test_data:
        params = line.split(',')
        cleanparams = getcleanparams(params)
        entry = Entry(cleanparams)
        self.test_entries.append(entry)

def testalgo(self):
    counter = 1
    P_diabetesyes = [0] * self.num_elements
    P_diabetesno = [0] * self.num_elements
    for entry in self.test_entries:
        pYesEntry = 1
        pNoEntry = 1
        pYesEntry, pNoEntry = self.test_Entry(pYesEntry, pNoEntry, P_diabetesyes, P_diabetesno, entry)

        pYesEntry *= float(self.p_diabetesyes)
        pNoEntry *= float(self.p_diabetesno)

        entry.set_ifdiabetes("yes") if (pYesEntry / pNoEntry >= 1) else entry.set_ifdiabetes("no")
        counter += 1

def test_Entry(self, pYesEntry, pNoEntry, P_diabetesyes, P_diabetesno, entry):
    for i in range(self.num_elements - 1):
        P_diabetesyes[i] = Decimal((1 / (self.b_diabetesyes[i] * m.sqrt(2 * m.pi))) * m.pow(m.e, (
                -m.pow(Decimal(entry.elements[i]) - self.a_diabetesyes[i], 2) / (
                2 * m.pow(self.b_diabetesyes[i], 2)))))
        P_diabetesno[i] = Decimal((1 / (self.b_diabetesno[i] * m.sqrt(2 * m.pi))) * m.pow(m.e, (
                -m.pow(Decimal(entry.elements[i]) - self.a_diabetesno[i], 2) / (
                2 * m.pow(self.b_diabetesno[i], 2)))))
        pYesEntry *= float(P_diabetesyes[i])
        pNoEntry *= float(P_diabetesno[i])

    return pYesEntry, pNoEntry
```

Comment: It looks like you're calculating statistics, so maybe you should be using a library that automates this.

Comment: Could you explain the goal of the function?

Comment: Google "python statistics library"

Comment: I am trying to implement Naive Bayes algorithm. I have now included the full code  here of the class.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any pre-existing libraries unfortunately.

Comment: use at least numpy for vector operations or at least write your own equivalent of numpy if you are not allowed to use it

Comment: `may be split the nested loop in two different nested loops and each writing in one line, e.g. for i,j in..`. This is an exact description of `itertools.product`. However, it would not improve your code or make it more efficient, it would just hide the nestedness of the loop behind a function call.

Comment: @Junuxx yes that's what I want to do actually, not really looking to make it more efficient. Can you please show me how it's done if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked me how to do this in the comments...

To get i,j indices for a nested loop in a single line of code, using itertools:

```
import itertools

for i, j in itertools.product(range(self.num_elements - 1),
                              range(self.num_diabetesyes)):
    diff_yes = self.diabetes_yes[i][j] - self.a_diabetesyes[i]
    sigSumYes[i] += m.pow(diff_yes, 2)

    diff_no = self.diabetes_no[i][j] - self.a_diabetesno[i]
    sigSumNo[i] += m.pow(diff_no, 2)
```

After that, have a separate for loop for the parts that only iterate over i.

```
for i in range(self.num_elements - 1):
    self.b_diabetesyes[i] = m.sqrt(sigSumYes[i] / (len(self.diabetes_yes[i]) - 1))
    self.b_diabetesno[i] = m.sqrt(sigSumNo[i] / (len(self.diabetes_no[i]) - 1))
```

Note, I don't think this is the best approach. Using Numpy and vector math would be much faster and more elegant.

Usually, "no libraries" rules in assigments mean "Don't use an off the shelf implementation of the algorithm you're asked to implement". Not "Don't use any external convenience classes whatsoever".

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still learning and not very skilled in using such libraries so I don't know how to efficiently use numpy and vector match here in this case. You must be right though. If you could show me that one as well that would be helpful.

Comment: @RafiulNakib: That would be a fairly extensive rewrite, but it would result in getting rid of pretty much all the for loops. For example, if  `self.diabetes_yes` and `self.a_diabetesyes` were numpy `ndarray`s, computing all `diff_yes` values would just be `self.diabetes_yes - self.a_diabetesyes`. Just take a look at a numpy tutorial when you get a chance :)

Comment: Another issue is, I just tried what you showed here and the output is not as same as before although it works fine. My original code gives 100% accuracy to what is expected as output. When I changed it to how you showed me, it reduces to 73% only.

Comment: Ah I guess one difference is that j only goes up to `self.num_diabetesyes`, while `self.num_diabetesno` might be higher. You could check for that to compensate but then it gets messier again.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe nobody dares to answer that you shouldn't always be looking further in changing your code, especially when it works. Most important pieces of software are often redondant and unreadable because of repetition. Just improve the functionnality or switch to a new software.

Comment: if ur code / core of software is unreadable then u need to change it to make it more readable and understandable, also downvoting because it doesn't solve OP problem

Comment: maybe that's because there is no problem at all

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to learn if a different approach is also possible IMO.

Comment: that's not a reason for downvoting the answer that would make the man really work instead of loosing time